# I would like to download multiple links in a directory

Tags: downloads

I apologize if I mispeak as I'm pretty new to the tech world. Basically i have a directory of server logs arranged accoring to the User's IP address. I am looking for a way to download every log in a directory without having to do so one at a time. Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make some assumptions about your question, so if they're wrong, please edit your question to clarify. First, I am assuming that you have two Ubuntu systems, one that is a web server called `server` that has your log files, and one that is a desktop system where you wish to download these files. Second, I'll assume that the server has `sshd` running to facilitate remote access, and that you can log in as a user called `user` with access to the log files.

To do this, I would run an `scp` command on the desktop system:

```
scp -r user@server:/path/to/get/log/files /path/to/put/log/files
```